# Reset Angular Countdown Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have a countdown directive that is counting down from the initial value that's in the element to 0 once a modal warns the user their session is about to timeout. Once the countdown reaches zero the user is prompted with a modal to either exit, or continue. If they hit continue, eventually if they get that same session expiration warning modal, the counter is then 0. I can't quite figure out how to reset the counter directive without just returning it and stopping it on all future warnings. Here's the code I have now.

```
.directive("ndCountdown", function($timeout, $compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var countdown = function(){
                var timer = element.find('strong');
                for(var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++){
                    var secs = parseInt(timer.text(), 10) - 1;
                    if(secs >= 0){
                        timer.text(secs);
                    } else{
                        //reset the element to the original value
                        //stop the timeout in this session but have it continue to 
                        //work in future dialogs.
                    }
                }
                $timeout(countdown, 1000);
            }
            countdown();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to save the variable of what is inside originally. Then only run the timeout if you are not at the end.

```
.directive("ndCountdown", function($timeout, $compile){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var timer = element.find('strong'),
            MAX   = parseInt(timer.text());
        var countdown = function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++){
                var secs = parseInt(timer.text(), 10) - 1;
                if(secs >= 0){
                    timer.text(secs);
                    $timeout(countdown, 1000);
                } else{
                    timer.text(MAX);
                }
            }
        }
        countdown();
    }
}
});
```

Now if you needed to be able to restart it, you would probably want to communicate something from your controller. Maybe a $broadcast like this. **be sure to inject $rootScope**

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event:start-countdown');
```

Then in your directive you add this at the end of your link function, and inject $rootScope. again.

```
$rootScope.$on('event:start-countdown', function() {
    countdown();
}
```